# How to use ScrolledThumbnail in wxpython

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

Here is my code however it doesnt work. There is not any examples of this widget that is available online. The following code returns an error. Im not too sure on how to use the ScrolledThumbnail widget, im hoping someone could show me and tell me what I am doing wrong.

```
import wx
from wx.lib.agw import thumbnailctrl as tn

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, style=wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE)
        self.button = wx.Button(self, -1, "Select dir")
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.ButtonPress, self.button)
        self.tn = tn.ScrolledThumbnail(self)
        self.tn.Bind(tn.EVT_THUMBNAILS_DCLICK, self.TnClick)

        box = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        box.Add(self.tn, 1, wx.EXPAND, 0)
        box.Add(self.button, 0, wx.ADJUST_MINSIZE, 0)
        self.SetSizer(box)
        box.Fit(self)
        self.Layout()

    def ButtonPress(self, evt):
        dlg = wx.DirDialog(self, 'Get dir')
        if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
            path = dlg.GetPath()
        dlg.Destroy()
        self.tn.ShowDir(path)

    def TnClick(self, evt):
        sel = self.tn.GetSelection()
        wx.MessageBox(self.tn.GetThumbInfo(sel))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.PySimpleApp(0)
    frame = MyFrame(None, -1, "")
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

EDIT:

here is the error

```
    self.tn.ShowDir(path)
  File "C:\Python29\lib\site-packages\wx-2.9.3-msw\wx\lib\agw\thumbnailctrl.py", line 1574, in ShowDir
    self._parent.RecreateComboBox(folder)
AttributeError: 'MyFrame' object has no attribute 'RecreateComboBox'
```

Comment: It would be more informative if you provided the text of the error, as this code works for me.

Comment: really did you try changing directories

Comment: Ok, I see. `ScrolledThumbnail` is not designed to use by itself, only within `ThumbnailCtrl` class. Why do you want to use it like that?

Comment: oh I thought thats how its done

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend looking at how the demo does it and then use the following wiki page to pull the demo code into your own: http://wiki.wxpython.org/Using%20wxPython%20Demo%20Code

The example you provide never calls "RecreateComboBox". However, from the error message, it would seem that you just don't have that method defined. If you define it, that error will not happen.

Answer (score 0):

The methods of ScrolledThumbnail are inherited in an eventual thumbnail instance. So you could use all these method by creating such an instance:

```
self.tn = tn.ThumbnailCtrl(panel, size = (500,500))
```

then call the method like this:

```
self.tn.SetDropShadow=False
```